# Time series change rate calculations for displaying trend line chart

Tags: dataset, time-series, infographics

I'm struggling to find a solution to produce a line chart which shows a trend from a Time Series metric.

I try to make my line chart look similar to the following:

[image: Time series]

Basically, I want to make use of relative change rates, but I struggle to find a calculation which makes a visualization as seen above possible. The graph should always be relative to a specific time window, meaning that I can query my data dynamically with a start and end timestamp.

My (incomplete) sample data set is the following:

```
timestamp,value,change_rate,change_rate_absolute_sum,change_rate_delta,change_rate_sum
1426587900000,778;0.00129,0.00129;0.00129,0.00129
1426588200000,778;0,0.00129;-0.00129,0
1426588500000,1189;0.52828,0.52957;0.52828,0.52828
1426588800000,1195;0.00505,0.53462;-0.52323,0.00505
1426589100000,1195;0,0.53462;-0.00505,0
1426589400000,1196;0.00084,0.53546;0.00084,0.00084
1426589700000,1286;0.07525,0.61071;0.07441,0.07525
1426590000000,1290;0.00311,0.61382;-0.07214,0.00311
1426590300000,1294;0.0031,0.61692;-0.00001,0.0031
1426590600000,1296;0.00155,0.61847;-0.00155,0.00155
1426590900000,1356;0.0463,0.66477;0.04475,0.0463
1426591200000,1358;0.00147,0.66624;-0.04483,0.00147
1426591500000,1358;0,0.66624;-0.00147,0
1426591800000,1360;0.00147,0.66771;0.00147,0.00147
1426592100000,1408;0.03529,0.703;0.03382,0.03529
1426592400000,1390;-0.01278,0.69022;-0.04807,-0.01278
1426592700000,1391;0.00072,0.69094;0.0135,0.00072
1426593000000,1410;0.01366,0.7046;0.01294,0.01366
1426593300000,1414;0.00284,0.70744;-0.01082,0.00284
1426593600000,1410;-0.00283,0.70461;-0.00567,-0.00283
1426593900000,1414;0.00284,0.70745;0.00567,0.00284
1426594200000,1420;0.00424,0.71169;0.0014,0.00424
1426594500000,1417;-0.00211,0.70958;-0.00635,-0.00211
```

Any ideas warmly appreciated. Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it is not very clear to me what specific relationships between your data you want to display, I can give some general advice. I think that this time series visualization calls for so-called [diverging color scheme](http://geog.uoregon.edu/datagraphics/color_scales.htm) (as opposed to *sequential*, *categorical* and other ones). [ColorBrewer](http://colorbrewer2.org) is nice online tool for selecting an appropriate *color scheme* and other parameters (note that *ColorBrewer*'s color schemes have built-in support in major data analysis and visualization software, such as R, Python, d3.js, plot.ly and others).

If you would use `R` environment, it would be quite easy to produce the time series *trend line chart* that you want by using `ggplot2` package and its `scale_color_gradient2()` function:

`... + scale_color_gradient2(midpoint=midValue, low="blue", mid="white", high="orange" )`

A quick glance at your profile suggested me that you would prefer a JavaScript solution. In that case, I would advise to use `d3.js` library or one of multiple other *JavaScript visualization* libraries or packages. For more details, check [this relevant answer](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/3723/2452) of mine.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! Maybe my question is not very clear, but I struggle more with the calculation of the Y value than with the diverging color scheme. I have the absolute values of the metric, but that doesn't really help me showing the "speed" of change, and if the "speed" is positive compared to the last "step"/"time bucket".

Comment: A line gradient solution with D3 can be found at http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/3e72cafd95e1834f599b and (better) http://codepen.io/ekrembk/pen/ights/ for example...

Comment: Have a look at http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PwxaRy Yet, the problem with the Y values remains... Do you have an idea?

Comment: You're very welcome! I couldn't display the result of your most recently referred code, as it's anon. Anyway, I don't see calculation of speed/rate of change as a problem. Rate of chage $R_i$ (for a time delta $\Delta t_i$) = $\frac{Y_{i+1} - Y_i}{\Delta t_i}$. So your $Y$ for the trend chart should be the $R_i$. What is the problem with that?

Comment: I already calculate the change rates. That's not the problem. Normally, the change rates (with my metric (except errors)) will be >= 0. What I want to with my graph is the "speed" that the values of the metric change from `t0` to `t1`. If the "speed" slows down, I want to show a negative trend. This is IMHO not possible with just the change rate.

Comment: @Tobi: Very easy (if I understand you correctly) - you just need to calculate [second derivative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_derivative) (rate of change of rate of change) at your predefined intervals. Those will be your $Y$ values.

Comment: Sorry for being a total noob at this. You mean as described at http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Numerical_Methods/Numerical_Differentiation#Second_Derivative

Comment: @Tobi: No need to apologize. Nobody knows everything :-). Yes, I believe that's the _quadratic approximation_. There are lots of resources on the topic. Have a look at [this discussion](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/810454), for example. Good luck and let me know, if I can be of more help!

Comment: Sorry, I'm still having problems with the calculation. Could you please give me an examle with the above provided sample data?

Comment: @Tobi: What language are we talking about? JavaScript? Also, does your column `change_rate_delta` contains already pre-calculated values, or `change_rate` should be used?

Comment: JavaScript/Node.js is my preferred language. As far as I understood, it should be possible to do the calc based on the raw metric values provided with the sample data. But I think I'm doing something wrong. Thanks again for your effort!